# Can anyone tell me where this is from or if it is just art?

Tags: aquarian-age

[image]

Hey all, need help with something - as the title states, can anyone tell me where this is from? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Intressting result I got here... The image, called *Coordinator Angel*, is drawn by *masterbimo* and can be found on his [DeviantART channel](http://masterbimo.deviantart.com/art/coordinator-angel-142665718).

This is a character from a trading card game called **Aquarian Age** (アクエリアンエイジ). It is a Japanese collectible card game similar to Magic.

> In the game, the player takes the role of a "Mindbreaker", who can
>   control and unlock the powers of the game characters. The goal is to
>   defeat other Mindbreakers (players) and to grow stronger. The game
>   continues until the player has defeated all of their opponents, or has
>   been stripped of their powers; thus being knocked out of the game.
>
> Unlike similar TCG, the player fields game characters instead of
>   spells. They must gain control over each character before it can be
>   used in a game. If a player is unable to control a character properly,
>   it may turn on them.

<sub>Information from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aquarian_Age).</sub>

Notice that the game was adapted into an anime series called **Aquarian Age: Sign for Evolution**.

[image: Cover]

- **Status**: Finished Airing
- **Aired**: Jan 11, 2002 to Mar 29, 2002
- **Genres**: Action, Adventure, Fantasy, Music, Romance, Sci-Fi, Shounen, Super Power, Supernatural
- **Episodes**: 13
- **Duration**: 24 min. per episode
- **Rating**: 13+

> Five supernatural factions have been fighting against each other for
>   who knows how many centuries, with the beginning of Aquarian Age
>   always in mind. Kyouta, soon begins to see visions of mystical girls
>   fighting, except they do exist. Soon he and his girlfriend Yoriko
>   become involved and the battle for Earth and Aquarian Age lies in
>   their hands.

<sub>Image from gzchunfeng. Information from [MyAnimeList](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1224/Aquarian_Age:_Sign_for_Evolution).</sub>